# Meteor React: User Object undefined at initial page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

On the profile page I want to disallow non-logged in users to access the page. However, the Meteor.user() object is undefined at initial page load. How should one wait till the Meteor.user() object is defined. When is it certain that the user is not logged in and the Meteor.user() is loaded?

Here is part of my Profile render method accompanied by the WithTracker method. As you can see there is a Redirect object being rendered when the Meteor.user() is unavailable.

```
render() {
  const {user} = this.props

  console.log(user) //First undefined, later defined. But already renders redirect, so it's not useful

  return (
    <Container fluid className='p-3 mb-5'>
      {/* Not logged in */}
      {!user && <Redirect
        to={{
        pathname: '/SignUp',
        state: {
          location: '/Profile'
        }
      }}/>}
      {/* Logged in */}
      ...
    </Container>
  )
}


export default withTracker(() => {
  return {
    user: Meteor.user()
  }
})(Profile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 return (
   { undefined === user ? <Container fluid className='p-3 mb-5'>
      {/* Not logged in */}
      {!user && <Redirect
        to={{
        pathname: '/SignUp',
        state: {
          location: '/Profile'
        }
      }}/>}
      {/* Logged in */}
      ...
    </Container> : 'loading'}
  )
```

You can try using `?` and `:` to run whats inside the container when user is `undefined` and to display loading indicator when it is `defined`.

Comment: Thank you @Omar. I placed the code in a higher order component, so I do not have to repeat it in every single component.

Comment: @Colin. The problem is that !user will trigger the redirect even if the user is not logged in. That is because the !user will always return true at initial page load. However, if you check if user === undefined, you will know it is loaded.

Comment: Why is the `user` always true at page load?